# Ampscript unknown reason for empty value in a variable

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have this ampscript:

```
%%[
var @id, @reference221, @reference222, @Apointer221, @ASKU221, @Apointer222, @ASKU222, @reference223, @reference224, @content222

SET @id = [email]
SET @reference221 = LookupRows("case2_2step1", "email", @id)

IF RowCount(@reference221) == 2 THEN

SET @reference222 = LookupOrderedRows("case2_2step1", 2, "email", "email", @id)
SET @Apointer221 = Row(@reference222, 1)
SET @ASKU221 = Field(@Apointer221, "sku")
SET @Apointer222 = Row(@reference222, 2)
SET @ASKU222 = Field(@Apointer222, "sku")
SET @reference223 = LookupRows("case2_2step3", "email", @id, "artikelnummer", @ASKU221)
SET @reference224 = LookupRows("case2_2step3", "email", @id, "artikelnummer", @ASKU222)

ENDIF

IF (@reference223 == 1 AND @reference224 == 1) THEN SET @content222 = 'A'
ELSEIF (@reference223 == 1 AND @reference224 > 1) OR (@reference223 > 1 AND @reference224 == 1) OR (@reference223 > 1 AND @reference224 > 1)
THEN SET @content222 = 'B' ENDIF

]%%

%%= v(@id) =%% <br>
%%= RowCount(@reference221) =%% <br>
%%= v(@ASKU221) =%% <br>
%%= v(@ASKU222) =%% <br>
%%= RowCount(@reference223) =%% <br>
%%= RowCount(@reference224) =%% <br>
%%= v(@content222) =%% <br>
```

All variables return values that I expect but somehow this @content222 returns nothing even though the variables (@reference223 and reference224) fulfil the IF ELSE condition. I'm banging my head on this. If anybody notice anything wrong please help

Comment: Is the `artikelnummer` field in your data extension a number or text data type?

Comment: the artikelnummer is text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to match data in the data extension, you need will need to ensure the types are also the same.  Since `artikelnummer` is set to `text`, you would want to change you `IF ELSE` statement to the following:

```
IF (@reference223 == '1' AND @reference224 == '1') THEN 
  SET @content222 = 'A'
ELSEIF (@reference223 == '1' AND @reference224 > '1') OR (@reference223 > '1' AND @reference224 == '1') OR (@reference223 > '1' AND @reference224 > '1')
THEN 
  SET @content222 = 'B' 
ENDIF
```

**Edit**
Turned out to be missing RowCount -

```
IF RowCount(@reference223) == 1 AND RowCount(@reference224) == 1 THEN 
   SET @content222 = 'A'
ELSEIF (RowCount(@reference223) == 1 AND RowCount(@reference224) > 1) OR (RowCount(@reference223) > 1 AND RowCount(@reference224) == 1) OR (RowCount(@reference223) > 1 AND RowCount(@reference224) > 1) THEN 
   SET @content222 = 'B'
```

Comment: I tried and @content222 always return B. I dont think the problem is in data type because when I call %%= RowCount(@reference223) =%% and %%= RowCount(@reference224) =%% it returns a correct value (in my case 1, 2 or 3) the returned value from the RowCount will always int if im not mistaken

Comment: Your are passing a number in the if statement, and the field is a string.

Comment: yes you are right, my mistake. your answer dont fix the problem but pointed out my mistake. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sorry its my mistake. I forget to put RowCount() function in the if else statement so the @reference223 and @reference224 contain text

here is the correct form of the if else statement

```
IF RowCount(@reference223) == 1 AND RowCount(@reference224) == 1 THEN SET @content222 = 'A'
ELSEIF (RowCount(@reference223) == 1 AND RowCount(@reference224) > 1) OR (RowCount(@reference223) > 1 AND RowCount(@reference224) == 1) OR (RowCount(@reference223) > 1 AND RowCount(@reference224) > 1)
THEN SET @content222 = 'B'
```

Comment: Yep,  I wasn't even looking at that portion.  That would be the issue

Comment: When you can, be sure to mark this as answered as well!